# How to increase bar spacing in altair

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to create an interactive chart such as when selecting a category, it displays all items in that category, but I haven't found a way to account for the variable height of the lower chart, which depends on the number of items in each category. This is how the chart ideally would show, when selecting category 1:

[image]

And when I select category 2, I would like it to be like this:

[image]

But, if I specify a fixed chart height that accommodates all the items in category 1 with proper spacing, this is what I get when I select category 2:

[image]

If I don't specify a chart height, the bars get too close together and some triangles don't show:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
df=pd.read_excel('df_test.xlsx')
    
    
domain=[df.Lowest.min(),df.Highest.max()]
    
    
selection=alt.selection_multi(fields=['category'],init=[{"category":"category1"}])
    
   
l=alt.Chart(df,height=80).mark_bar(color='red',size=15).encode(alt.X('min(Lowest)',scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain))
            ,alt.Y('category'),x2='max(middle)')
h=alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(color='green',size=15).encode(alt.X('max(middle)',scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain))
            ,alt.Y('category'),x2='max(Highest)')
avg_triangle=alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=300,shape='triangle',filled=True,yOffset=-16,angle=180).encode(
    alt.X('mean(Current)',scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain)),alt.Y('category'))

averages=alt.layer(l,h,avg_triangle).add_selection(selection)


low=alt.Chart(df,height=300).mark_bar(color='red',size=15).encode(alt.X('Lowest',scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain))
                ,alt.Y('items'),x2='middle')

high=alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(color='green',size=15).encode(alt.X('middle',scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain))
                ,alt.Y('items'),x2='Highest')

triangle=alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=300,shape='triangle',filled=True,yOffset=-16,angle=180).encode(
    alt.X('Current',scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain)),alt.Y('items'))
    
items=alt.layer(low,high,triangle).transform_filter(selection)
    

alt.vconcat(averages,items).configure_axis(title=' ')
```

And this is the dataset:

[image]

And the data for easy grab:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([{'category': 'category1',
  'items': 'c1-item1',
  'Highest': 77.9674166,
  'Lowest': 64.76344086,
  'middle': 71.36542873,
  'Current': 70.11278195},
 {'category': 'category1',
  'items': 'c1-item2',
  'Highest': 85.71428571,
  'Lowest': 64.38053097,
  'middle': 75.04740834,
  'Current': 84.1},
 {'category': 'category1',
  'items': 'c1-item3',
  'Highest': 82.51879699,
  'Lowest': 62.63736264,
  'middle': 72.578079815,
  'Current': 81.2},
 {'category': 'category1',
  'items': 'c1-item4',
  'Highest': 80.47182176,
  'Lowest': 51.37362637,
  'middle': 65.922724065,
  'Current': 76.69172932},
 {'category': 'category1',
  'items': 'c1-item5',
  'Highest': 85.19003932,
  'Lowest': 55.43010753,
  'middle': 70.310073425,
  'Current': 83.64661654},
 {'category': 'category1',
  'items': 'c1-item6',
  'Highest': 79.45609436,
  'Lowest': 40.56776557,
  'middle': 60.01192996499999,
  'Current': 74.81203008},
 {'category': 'category2',
  'items': 'c2-item1',
  'Highest': 76.14678899,
  'Lowest': 50.0,
  'middle': 63.073394495,
  'Current': 69.17293233},
 {'category': 'category2',
  'items': 'c2-item2',
  'Highest': 81.06159895,
  'Lowest': 58.77956989,
  'middle': 69.92058442,
  'Current': 75.0}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the number of pixels used for [each discrete step](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/size.html#specifying-width-and-height-per-discrete-step) (i.e. each bar) by using `{"step": <number>}`. You can also create more space between bars by narrowing the bars themselves with `bandPaddingInner`:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})

alt.Chart(source, width=alt.Step(100)).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b'
).configure_scale(
    bandPaddingInner=0.5
)
```

[image]

You will also need to add `.configure(autosize=alt.AutoSizeParams(resize=True))` to the end of your concatenated chart in order for the overall chart size (not just the axes) to [update on a selection](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2512#issuecomment-965600160).

In the next version of Altair you will be able to dynamically change the height of a chart [using parameters](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/parameter.html#built-in-variable-parameters).

Comment: @jolelostblom My understanding is that the importance of the question is whether it is possible to dynamically resize the graph. I think the order of the answers are different. Sorry for pointing out the details.

Comment: @joelostblom Thanks so much for the answer. Unfortunately, I am planning to add more elements such as text above the triangle and another triangle with text below the bars, so it won't all fit even with narrowing the bars. I'm wondering if there is a way to access the values in the selection in order to use them as variables. For dynamically changing the height, as you show above, using the number of items in the selection. But also, the name of the selection could be used for the title of the bottom chart.

Comment: @joelostblom I have a few more unrelated questions about other features in this visualization. Should I start a new question? Or, should I ask them here?

Comment: @flbyrne Thanks for the additional details! I updated my answer to show how you can also increase the overall chart width by assigning a width per bar, which together with the band padding should allow space for your triangles and annotations.

If you have unrelated follow ups, please ask again in a separate question and try to include an as simple example as possible, preferably using a sample data set as in my answer above.

Comment: @flbyrne I also added a note on autosizing of the entire chart on selections.

Comment: @joelostblom Is there an alternate syntax for defining the steps width={"step": 100}? It works fine on my notebook, but the dictionary notation throws an error when I deploy to google app engine. I was having the same problem when I specified chart titles in dictionary form, which got fixed by using alt.TitleParams instead.

Comment: @joelostblom btw, .configure(autosize=alt.AutoSizeParams(resize=True)) doesn't change anything, because the autosizing is the default mode, but the steps make it possible to control the width of the autosizing.

Comment: @flbyrne Yes you can use `alt.Step(100)`, I updated the answer with that. Strange that the autosize does not have an effect for you, it did for me when I tried with your example.

Comment: @joelostblom now I realized how the autosize has an effect. If the initial choice has more items than subsequent choices, which was my case, there won't be any difference whether you add the autosize or not, But if you don't add the autosize and your initial chart is smaller, it will remain smaller for the choice where you have more items, so the lower ones won't be visible. I run into this on a new chart that I made.

Comment: @flbyrne Thanks for coming back to this. I think technically the autosize might still have an effect if the initial choice has the most items, but you might not be able to see it easily since it would become empty space below the chart when you select fewer items. But if you have a concatenated chart it should be visible what is happening.